# bootstrap max-height not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Hey guys so I have a bootstrap site and I've built a fairly basic header file that looks like this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        nav a{
            color: white
        }
        nav {background-color: #1c71b9; }
        .navbar-toggle{border: 3px solid white;}
        .icon-bar{background-color: white;}
        .navbar-brand:hover{background-color: white;
        color: #1c71b9;
        }
        body{margin-top: 50px;}
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p{
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }
        .row + .row{margin-top: 20px;}
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vue.js"></script>
</head>

<header>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">My Site</a>
        </div><!--end .navbar-header-->
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Subscriptions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stock</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end #navbar-->
     </div><!--end container-->
    </nav>
     <div class="container">
      <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <!--modal header-->
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Login</h2>
                </div>
                <!--modal body-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username/Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username/Email" id="username" name="username">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Username</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!--modal footer-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </header>
```

I included this header file into my index.php document and am trying to make a video that spans 100% of the browser in width and have a max-height of 800px but its not working no matter what I do the video has white space on the sides without spanning all of the width. Any help here would be great! I basically want the video to always be centered and responsive. Similar to the img-responsive class does. Heres a copy of the index file

```
<?php require_once('header.php');?>
<style>
.videoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.videoContainer video {
  /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */
  min-width: 100%; 
  max-height: 800px; 

  /* Setting width & height to auto prevents the browser from stretching or squishing the video */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  /* Center the video */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
</style>
<body>
    <div align="center" class="videoContainer">
    <video src="Balloon.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
    </div>
</body><?php require_once('header.php');?>
<style>
.videoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.videoContainer video {
  /* Make video to at least 100% wide and tall */
  min-width: 100%; 
  max-height: 800px; 

  /* Setting width & height to auto prevents the browser from stretching or squishing the video */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  /* Center the video */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
</style>
<body>
    <div align="center" class="videoContainer">
    <video src="Balloon.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: so your body starts after the <header> tag ?, isn't that supposed to start before header right after head ??

Comment: Your right I fixed it still having problem.

Comment: can you post a snippet or fiddle, that would be the easier for others to inspect your issues

Comment: Maybe you can use "100vw" instead of "100%" (viewport width), maybe i'm totally wrong but hope it helps.

Comment: tried that but it doesn't work. The place where I work is blocking jsfiddle at the moment. Can one of you guys copy the code and try it there?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap wrap video inside a container-fluid. This spans the entire width of the viewport ([view documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers)). You can try something like this:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <video src="Balloon.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true"></video>
 </div>
```

then in your css:

```
 div video {
     height: 800 px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you video to cover full width of you div do not set height for the video, videos will always keep its aspect ratio, so if you set height the width will also reduce according to that. so the best way would be set height for the div wrapping the video the let the video to expand 100%